# Python main function in class

Tags: python, class, program-entry-point, bloom-filter

I'm new to python and the main() method and class def's are confusing me. I'm trying to create a bloom filter and my program keeps terminating because I don't think I'm calling things correctly.

```
    class BloomFilter(object):
        def __init__(self, numBits, numHashFunctions):
            self.numBits = numBits
            self.bitArray = [0] * numBits
            self.hash = bloomFilterHash(numBits, numHashFunctions)

        def insert(self, key):

        def lookup(self, key):

        def rand_inserts(self,num):

        def main(): #not sure if i should put this inside or outside class
            bloomfilter = BloomFilter(100,5)
            bloomfilter.rand_inserts(15)

    if __name__ == '__main__':   
        BloomFilter().main()
```

So if I wanted to create a bloom filter with 100 numBits and 5 hash functions, should i call that  under the `if __name__ == '__main__'` or under `def main()`? I'm not sure if I'm calling these correctly as I'm much more familiar with Java. thanks!

```
    def main():
        bloomfilter = BloomFilter(100,5)
        bloomfilter.rand_inserts(15)
```

Comment: There is no special "main" function in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `name == '__main__'` clause is to make sure your code only runs when the module is called directly, not, for instance, if you are importing something from the module in another module. `main()` is not a special method for a python class, so I believe your objective here, in a simplified way, is the following:

```
class BloomFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, numBits, numHashFunctions):
        self.numBits = numBits
        self.bitArray = [0] * numBits
        self.hash = bloomFilterHash(numBits, numHashFunctions)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # creates an instance of the class
    bloomfilter = BloomFilter(100,5)
    # apply some method to instance...
    bloomfilter.rand_inserts(15)
```

Answer (score 2):

You would want to put main() outside the class:

```
class BloomFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, numBits, numHashFunctions):
        self.numBits = numBits
        self.bitArray = [0] * numBits
        self.hash = bloomFilterHash(numBits, numHashFunctions)

    def insert(self, key):

    def lookup(self, key):

    def rand_inserts(self,num):



 def main():
     some_value = Bloomfilter(100, 5)

     some_value.rand_inserts(15)

 main()
```